# Upload videos to picasa using .NET api

Tags: google-api, picasa

I cannot find anything on the api page from google, is this even possible? I cant find anything on the web

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure: your can upload images, videos or other binary files in C#, or any other .Net language:

http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/1.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#PostPhotos**
**

Here's the complete GData .Net API:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/

Comment: Can you give me an example or direct me to one, as I said in my post they DO NOT have any examples. Only Java doc has examples.

Comment: Did you look at the "Post a new photo" link I cited above?  It sure looks like an "example" to me ;)

Comment: sorry maybe I should be more clear, I tried to upload a video to picasa and got this  "A direct media post of videos is currently not supported" thats why i need an example of how to upload a VIDEO

Comment: So THAT'S the problem: "A direct media post of videos is currently not supported".  The code snippet just opens a binary filestream to a Picasa URI with a specific MIME type ("image/jpeg").  Apparently Picasa doesn't like your MIME type.  Q: Why didn't you mention the error in your original post?  Q: Are you using one of these:  http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#PostVideo?   Q: Have you Googled for that error message?

Comment: I Googled the error message, and found this:  http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#UploadVideos  NOTE: you need to upload the video with metadata.  ALSO NOTE: you'd get exactly the same problem in Java as .Net if you *don't* upload with metadata.

Comment: no, There is no way to add metadata such as a property or a method to add it for that picasaPhoto class.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help people out who is trying to upload videos to picasa using the .NET API.

```
RequestSettings mySettings = new RequestSettings("PROGRAM NAME");
            mySettings.Timeout = 600000; 
            PicasaRequest pr = new PicasaRequest(mySettings);
            PicasaService service = pr.Service;
            service.setUserCredentials(username, password);
            Uri postUri = new Uri(PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri(username, picasaalbumid));

 PhotoEntry videoEntry = new PhotoEntry();
                videoEntry.Title = new AtomTextConstruct(AtomTextConstructElementType.Title,"Untitled.3gp");//I would change this to read the file type, This is just an example
                videoEntry.Summary = new AtomTextConstruct(AtomTextConstructElementType.Summary,"");
                MediaFileSource source = new MediaFileSource(stream,fileName,fileType);
                videoEntry.MediaSource = source;
                PicasaEntry entry = service.Insert(postUri,videoEntry);
                stream.Close();
```